# Trying to Sign into AWS Elasticsearch to be able to use elasticsearch-php

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-efs

I have checked into the following sources for signing into elasticsearch:
https://github.com/wizacha/AwsSignatureMiddleware
Which I don't want to use because it asks for direct call to secret and key.

https://github.com/jeskew/amazon-es-php
Which looked promising, because it uses the PHP SDK routine for authentication from default. But I am getting 500 error whenever I call to index function of the client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/es-data-plane.html
This looks like I can sign in directly with AWS ES SDK, but I don't understand the properties I would need to pass for:

```
$signedRequest = $signer->signRequest($psr7Request, $credentials);
```

It says it "assumed in the code below to be named $psr7Request"??? What does that mean, what I am I supposed to pass for the psr7Request?

Can anyone tell me a detailed solution for one of these three options? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the text "a PSR-7 request (assumed in the code below to be named $psr7Request)", "PSR-7" is actually a link that provides more info:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Psr.Http.Message.RequestInterface.html

Comment: That is just an api, it doesn't really tell me what to pass in or what is expected for my signRequest?

Comment: Also, I am using environment variables for credentials, so not sure why that has to be passed too?